# How do I add for loop index to the JSP variable

Tags: jsp, jstl

How do I add logic to do for loop only if `${link[i].alt}` is not empty?
How to add index to the jsp var ...like `${link${i}.credit}`??

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="6">
    <li>${i}
        <a class="lnid-sec1_lnk${i}" href="${link.href}">
            <div class="l-wrapper">
                <img data-src="${link1.credit}" src="${link1.credit}" alt="${link1.alt}" width="100">
                <div class="team-name">
                    <span>${link1.alt}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ans:1

```
<c:if test="${!empty link[i].alt}"></c:if>
```

Ans: 2

```
<c:set var="your_var" value="${link[i.index].credit}"/>
```

Comment: <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="6">
                    ${link1.credit}-- Link 1 credit
                    ${i}** - index
                    ${link[i.index].credit}-- Link credits from the loop - not returning the value  //data i am getting is social-.jpg-- Link 1 credit 1** - index -- Link credits from the loop

Comment: <c:forEach var ="i" begin="1" end="6" varStatus="item">
                    ${link[item.index].alt}  -- Not working too

Answer (score 1):

add varStatus

so

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="6" varStatus="yourIndex">
```

Then

(${yourIndex.index}) contains the index

Comment: Thanks for answering. But <c:forEach var ="i" begin="1" end="6" varStatus="item">
                    ${link[item.index].alt} -- not working

Answer (score 0):

For not empty you can use this

```
<c:if test="${!empty link[i].alt}"></c:if>
```